# Find the values of x for which the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-1)^n}{(-3)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the values of x for which the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-1)^n}{(-3)^n}$$

converge?

Not really sure how to properly answer this question considering its edge terms. Here goes my attempt: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x-1}{-3}\right)^n$$

I know by the geometric series test that the only way for this geometric serise to be convergent is if $|r| < 1$

$$|x-1| < 3$$

$$\leftrightarrow -3 < (x-1) < 3$$

$$\leftrightarrow -2 < x < 4$$

Therefore this series converges for $x \in (-2,4)$

Is this a good enough answer? I know it doesn't converge for 4 or -2.

Comment: typo on your final statement, you wrote $x-1$, think you meant $x$. And simply, yes it is a good enough answer for me at least.

Comment: You can use ratio test ?

Comment: Never learned ratio test yet. And thank you robin

Comment: Yeah it looks good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close by saying you don't know if it converges when $x = 4$ or $x = -2$.

At these values, note that $x-1 = 3$ or $-3$, respectively, so that in the former case you would be considering the infinite series $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ and in the latter you have $1+1+1+\cdots$

Each of these series diverges, as the $n^{\text{th}}$ terms do not converge to $0$.